# How to calculate cache access time using gem5 simulator

Tags: gem5

I used gem5 simulator to run my program,
it generate stats.txt in m5out directory,
but in the stats.txt, I don't know how to calculate the cache access time.

Comment: `data_latency` and `response_latency` I would guess? It would be cool to verify it however with a bare metal program and `--debug-flags=Exec` logging.